# Editing pages from dashboard

Tags: pages, dashboard, content

I keep struggling to understand how and why this happens: in some themes I can modify the content of a page (type page) from the dashboard, in others I can't. For instance, if I activate a default theme, say Twenty Fifteen, I can create and edit pages from dashboard. When I creat a theme from scratch, I can add a new page from dashboard, but the content added there is not showing up in the website so editing isn't possible either (my theme has only few files created: 404, footer, header, functions, index.php and style.css). When I visualize a page in the website (local), it displays the index.php content instead of the content from the dashboard. So what is the difference between the wp default themes and the one I created from zero? Please help me understand this. I didn't find any satisfying explanations on Google and posting here is kind of my last resort. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to display page content in custom theme you should use `page.php` template,
and call `the_content()` inside the **loop**.
You can also create custom template for different pages and assign them in back end.
See: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Comment: So this is the main practice? Now, that I saw your explanation, I checked again the code behind Twenty fifteen theme and saw they used the_content() as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use the word press default loop  for getting posts.

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        // Your loop code
         the_content();
    endwhile;
else :
    echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
endif;
?>
```